# How to prevent Windows 10 Update from restarting my PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

In the Advanced Windows Update Options, I've set Windows Update to "Notify to schedule restart".

It still restarts my machine if I ignore the prompt to schedule a restart.

Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your local group policy settings to force Windows update to only download updates, but wait for your input to install (and therefore reboot.)

Open you start menu and type **Group**, then click **Edit group policy**

Expand **Computer Configuration** \ **Administrative Templates** \ **Windows Components** \ **Windows Update**

[image: Local Group Policy Editor - Windows Update]

Double click **Configure Automatic Updates** and enable the policy, and configure it as needed.

[image: Configure Automatic Updates]

Head back to Windows Update and click **Check for updates**, once it is done click on the **Advanced options**

You should see your new settings being 'enforced.'

[image: Enforced Windows Update settings]